# .ant-targets-build.xml puts eclipse project into error

Tags: eclipse, ant

I am using the most excellent ant/bin/complete-ant-cmd.pl for bash completion of ant targets and it caches its results in a file called .ant-targets-build.xml.  The problem is, in my eclipse project, eclipse is a little overaggressive validating everything it believes is actually XML (which .ant-targets-build.xml isn't...its just the raw targets separated by newlines).

How do I get eclipse to relax its restrictions and treat .ant-targets-build.xml as NOT an xml file...just text or something.

Comment: Oh, yeah, eclipse complains with "Content is not allowed in prolog."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Project->Properties

- Check `Enable project specific settings`.
- Click ellipsis next to `XML Validator`

[image: Project properties]

- Click on `Exclude Group`
- Click on `Add Rule`

[image: Validation rules]

Follow wizard and create `File` exclusion.

One of the most annoying "features" of this dialog is that you cannot edit existing rules.  If you make a mistake you will need to delete that rule and recreate it from scratch.

BTW, in your case it may be preferable to create a global workspace rule ( I usually like to keep special cases with the project ).

In any case after you finished with rule creation, right-click on a project with warnings and choose `Validate`.  This will clear these warnings

If you decided to edit validation preferences in project and not in workspace, then add `project-name/.setting/org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs` file to source control.